# Angularjs accordion ng-click on panel-header

Tags: angularjs, accordion, angular-ui-bootstrap

In AngularJS UI Bootstrap I want to activate **isopen** when **panel-heading** is clicked, but I couldn't find a way.
In this version is activated only if you click the link.

Here's what I tried;

```
<accordion-group is-open="isopen">
    <accordion-heading ng-click="isopen=!isopen">
        I can have markup, too! 
        <i class="pull-right glyphicon" 
           ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-down': isopen, 'glyphicon-chevron-right': !isopen}"></i>
    </accordion-heading>
    This is just some content to illustrate fancy headings.
</accordion-group>
```

**ng-click="isopen=!isopen**"

[This is the link I tried on Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ODaYSMnLWQ6mdNYmYnSu?p=preview)

[AngularJS UI Bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/getting_started)

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 60, accepted):

**EDIT:**
A better solution is to move `ng-click="isopen=!isopen"` to the `accordion-group` element. This way the panel is opened/closed clicking anywhere on the panel-heading, including the edges.

```
<accordion close-others="oneAtATime">
    <accordion-group is-open="isopen" ng-click="isopen=!isopen">
        <accordion-heading >
           I can have markup, too! 
           <i class="pull-right glyphicon" 
              ng-class="{'glyphicon-   chevron-down': isopen, 'glyphicon-chevron-right': !isopen}">
           </i>
        </accordion-heading>
        This is just some content to illustrate fancy headings.
    </accordion-group>
</accordion>
```

**END EDIT**

enclose the content of `<accordion-heading>` in a `<div>`

```
<accordion close-others="oneAtATime">
    <accordion-group is-open="isopen" >
        <accordion-heading ng-click="isopen=!isopen">
           <div>
            I can have markup, too! 
           <i class="pull-right glyphicon" 
              ng-class="{'glyphicon-   chevron-down': isopen, 'glyphicon-chevron-right': !isopen}">
           </i>
           </div>
       </accordion-heading>
       This is just some content to illustrate fancy headings.
   </accordion-group>
</accordion>
```

Comment: But this way it is closed, if you click on panel-body

Comment: The `isopen` is not necessary here, the solution with the enclosing `div` is perfect without the custom `isopen` variable.

Comment: There's a problem with this approach, it only makes the text area clickable but not the whole control so if you click near the edges it won't work.  You can see from here http://plnkr.co/edit/0aiIabxogB1oKIhbjHXa

Comment: @ArchimedesTrajano move the `ng-click` attribute to the `accordion-group` element. see this plunkr http://plnkr.co/edit/IshCNSF6jjWBt9BCukTz?p=preview

Comment: you need to change the plnkr slightly so there's no space in the glypicons-chevron-down

Comment: yours has one extra side effect though (which may be good on some cases but not all the time) it will toggle when you click on the expanded area.

Comment: @ArchimedesTrajano you are right ... did you find how to fix it?

Comment: I had to change the template itself.  My answer is below

Comment: @ArchimedesTrajano yeah, to change the directive template is the most accurate solution +1

Comment: ng-click on group restricts me type in the textbox tht is inside the acoordion

Comment: @klode can you please help me to solve this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50073157/data-api-response-not-binding-in-accordion-in-angular4

Comment: Using the div element did not work for me. Moving the ng-click event to the "accordion-group" tag DID work for me. :-)  My custom function is always called regardless of what is clicked (title or glyph).

Answer (score 14):

A very simple CSS-based solution:

```
    .panel-heading {
        padding: 0;
    }

    .panel-title a {
        display: block;
        padding: 10px 15px;
    }
```

I'm not using complex headings though - just the heading attribute as shown below, so I haven't tested it with the examples above.

```
<uib-accordion-group heading="Details" class="form-horizontal" is-open="true">
```

Comment: That's exactly what I needed, and very simple. Thanks! (and I'm using `<uib-accordion-heading>`, though a basic one)

Comment: @Sean can you please help me to solve this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50073157/data-api-response-not-binding-in-accordion-in-angular4

Answer (score 10):

What you need to do is change the `accordion-group.html` template such that it makes the header take the `ng-click` event.

```html
<div class="panel {{panelClass || 'panel-default'}}">
  <div class="abc panel-heading" ng-keypress="toggleOpen($event)" ng-click="toggleOpen($event)" >
    <h4 class="panel-title">
      <a href tabindex="0" class="accordion-toggle" accordion-transclude="heading"><span ng-class="{'text-muted': isDisabled}">{{heading}}</span></a>
    </h4>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-collapse collapse" collapse="!isOpen">
      <div class="panel-body" ng-transclude></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then in your code specify it as the template-url for the `accordion-group`

```html
<accordion-group heading="Dynamic Body Content" template-url="accordion-group.html">
```

Example: 
http://plnkr.co/edit/EXUgyNi8hrqQbh5maJUx?p=preview

Comment: This is the right thing to do. It works like a charm !

Comment: @AlexandreD. can you please help me to solve this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50073157/data-api-response-not-binding-in-accordion-in-angular4