# How can I open one accordion-group when I click to close another accordion-group?

Tags: angularjs, accordion, angular-ui-bootstrap

Here is my accordion:

```
<accordion class="m3Details">
    <accordion-group is-open="status.isFirstOpen" is-disabled="status.isFirstDisabled">
      <accordion-heading><span class="noQuery">Building<span class="caret"></span></span></accordion-heading>

        <li ng-repeat="y in m3Info" class="{{y.linkclass}}" ng-if="!y.offsite" ><a href="{{y.link}}" ng-click="clickLinks(y.initialOut,y.initialIn,y.backIn,y.backOut,y.name)"><img src="{{y.icon}}" width="15px" height="15px">{{y.name}}</a></li>

    </accordion-group>

    <accordion-group>
      <accordion-heading ng-click="isFirstOpen=!isFirstOpen"><span>Offsites<span class="caret"></span></span></accordion-heading>

        <li ng-repeat="y in m3Info" class="{{y.linkclass}}" ng-if="y.offsite"><a href="{{y.link}}" ng-click="clickLinks(y.initialOut,y.initialIn,y.backIn,y.backOut,y.name)"><img src="{{y.icon}}" width="15px" height="15px">{{y.name}}</a></li>

    </accordion-group>
</accordion>
```

This code works beautifully up to a certain point. The first group is always open and I have the header hidden so it cannot be toggled by the user. It opened, however, when the 2nd accordion header is closed. Perfect. But now, I want it to open again when the 2nd accordion is closed, so that they cannot be both closed at the same time.

I added in the `ng-click="isFirstOpen=!isFirstOpen"` in attempt to accomplish this as I have found it as a solution to closing an accordion when a button or something else is clicked. But it's not working when I put it in my accordion. Maybe I am putting it in wrong place or otherwise implementing it wrong? Perhaps there is another approach?

Thanks.

---

Using the answer by kjv here [Handle open/collapse events of Accordion in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15642082/handle-open-collapse-events-of-accordion-in-angular) where it was suggested to put the ng-click inside the heading, around the text like so:

```
<accordion-heading><span ng-click="status.isFirstOpen=!status.isFirstOpen">Offsites<span class="caret"></span></span></accordion-heading>
```

When I click it, it starts to open for a split second and then closes. I am simply looking for a way to have one accordion-group closing open another.

---

I have a working plunker that replicates my results.
http://plnkr.co/edit/04SZ0T2hHAmuH7o11faH?p=preview

**All that I need to see is this plunkr fixed to show that one accordion will open when another closes. Is it not possible to open an accordion when one is closed??**

I have even tried to put the ng-click back in the `accordion-heading` and wrap a `div` tag around the content of `accordion-heading` according to this answer: [Angularjs accordion ng-click on panel-header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23135832/angularjs-accordion-ng-click-on-panel-header) and still have not had any success.

Comment: did you try status.isFirstOpen = !status.isFirstOpen

Comment: @KevinF That would seem to make more sense. However, it too is giving same results.. nothing. :(

Comment: Will you please create a jsfiddle for us ?

Comment: @Vineet Sure, gimme a few.

Comment: Did you try just using the built in close-others attribute?

Comment: @jme11 Doesn't do anything... but unless it also opens others I wouldn't expect it to. I want the first accordion-group to open when the second accordion-group closes.

Comment: @Vineet Alright I have finally successfully put together a plunkr. I had to use a working on https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ and change it to get it to recplicate my results. As you can see, The first list starts out open, then closes when "offsites" is clicked. I need it to open again when offsites is clicked again. http://plnkr.co/edit/04SZ0T2hHAmuH7o11faH?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to alienx's answer to my question here: [How can I disable an accordion-group *after* I open it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30716402/how-can-i-disable-an-accordion-group-after-i-open-it)

I was able to understand more of how to use `booleans` to manipulate functionality. Here is **the solution** to my question:

HTML

```
<accordion class="m3Details" close-others="false">
    <accordion-group is-open="buildingsOpen">
        <accordion-heading><span class="noQuery">Building<span class="caret"></span></span></accordion-heading>

            <li ng-repeat="y in m3Info" class="{{y.linkclass}}" ng-if="!y.offsite"><a href="{{y.link}}" ng-click="clickLinks(y.initialOut,y.initialIn,y.backIn,y.backOut,y.name)"><img src="{{y.icon}}" width="15px" height="15px">{{y.name}}</a></li>


    </accordion-group>

    <accordion-group ng-click="runThis()">
        <accordion-heading><span>Offsites<span class="caret"></span></span></accordion-heading>
            <li ng-repeat="y in m3Info" class="{{y.linkclass}}" ng-if="y.offsite"><a href="{{y.link}}" ng-click="clickLinks(y.initialOut,y.initialIn,y.backIn,y.backOut,y.name)"><img src="{{y.icon}}" width="15px" height="15px">{{y.name}}</a></li>

    </accordion-group>

</accordion>
```

For some reason using the `status.isFirstOpen` code, for example:

```
$scope.status={
    isFirstOpen:true,
}
```

that is found in the docs of the Angular Accordion weren't as easily manipulated as the following:

JS

```
$scope.buildingsOpen = true;

  $scope.runThis = function() {
    $scope.buildingsOpen=!$scope.buildingsOpen;
}
```

Works [*perfect*](http://plnkr.co/edit/N71sJzxwEJNi1BtJBuDk?p=preview).

I knew it had to be *that* simple, maybe I didn't explain my question very well.